# i need help to reduce Excel Timeline's range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, datamodel

i think this is a simple problem, but can't wrap my head around it.. I have 3 tables that have "Date" in them and are all connected in the data model using the "Calendar table" that Excel Data model lets you build.

[image]

my issue is that when i now want to add a "timeline" in my dashboard (so that all my pivot charts update as i select my date range), the time line contains all years and not just the ones that i have data for (2019 to current), the timeline pulls all the way to 1975 (but nothing has data until 2019).. Can the timeline be "trimmed" to only 2019 to current?

I tried filtering the first "Date" column in the data model (what i assume is where the timeline pulls data from), but they still show up on the actual timeline...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i guss [date] column may contain blank cells or other text cells, if so then would like to suggest you remove all these cells except dates.
but not sure so let me see your whole excel file.